# Efficient way of implementing SparseMatrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, out-of-memory, sparse-matrix

I have huge matrix, but many of the entries are empty.

So I tried to use a vector of AVL trees, where the length of the vector is around 20<sup>7</sup> and each AVL tree has around 110,000 nodes (for a total of 20<sup>7</sup> · 110,000 nodes).

But now when I increase the problem size to 90,000, I get a "GC OverHeader limit exceeded" error, because there are too many nodes and I've configured my JVM with a max-heap size of 2 GB.

I wonder if there is an other way to implement a sparse matrix efficiently?

If it helps: I don't need to be able to modify the sparse-matrix after creating it. I just need to build it once, and then get efficient lookup.

Comment: @ruakh i am using Java and i have allocated 2 GB.

Comment: I don't need to modify it but all i want is efficient lookup.

Comment: 2GB heap is pretty small for such a problem.  Add memory to your machine and increase the heap size to a reasonable number like 8GB

Comment: Isn't 20^7 the same as 1.28 **billion**? Which would make 20^7 * 110000 equal to 141 **trillion**.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good summary of sparse matrix data structures at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix but of course it all depends on what you need to do with it. If all you need is lookup, I would expect a hash table to be more space-efficient than a balanced tree. It shouldn't take long to try java.util.HashMap.